# Installing Modellus X on Debian, libglass.so required

Tags: java, linux

Today I downloaded Modellux X from https://modellus5.googlecode.com/files/ModellusX_unix_0_4_04.sh

After allow it to execute and checked Java version I proceed to install, with no errors.

When I try to execute I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/javier/ModellusX/amd64/libglass.so

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:124)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:182)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:199)
at Modellus.WinUI.Animator.AnimationPanel.<init>(AnimationPanel.java:39)
at Modellus.WinUI.InternalFrames.AnimatorInternalFrame.<init>(AnimatorInternalFrame.java:25)
at Modellus.WinUI.ModellusFrame.ModellusFrame.createAndShowGUI(ModellusFrame.java:301)
at Modellus.WinUI.ModellusFrame.ModellusFrame.access$100(ModellusFrame.java:40)
at Modellus.WinUI.ModellusFrame.ModellusFrame$8.run(ModellusFrame.java:326)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The java version is

```
  javier@javier-Aspire-5536 ~ $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

My system info

```
javier@javier-Aspire-5536 ~ $ uname -v
#29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013
javier@javier-Aspire-5536 ~ $ uname -r
3.8.0-19-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this bug, you must to copy all  native javaFX libraries from your $JRE_PATH/lib/amd64" to "~/ModelusX/amd64" folder. The native JAVAFX libraries are:

[image]

To moore detail about native JAVAFX libraries, [Click here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-7-readme-429198.html)